# Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)- unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

Please tell me, I'm trying to figure out CEF in the simplest example.

I downloaded precompiled CEF binaries for windows:https://cef-builds.spotifycdn.com/index.html

There was an example inside - I launched and built it, compiled an exe file, it starts and works.

**1**.Now I have created a new project in VS2019 - connected to it the cef_sandbox.lib file and the header files that were in the example.

**2**.Compiled an empty main() - everything was compiled.

**3**.Now I'm adding just one CEF function from the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#include "include/cef_command_line.h"
#include "include/cef_sandbox_win.h"
#include "tests/cefsimple/simple_app.h"

#pragma comment(lib,cef_sandbox.lib")

int main()
{
    CefEnableHighDPISupport();
}
```

But an error occurs:

> Error LNK2019 reference to an unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
> Cef Enable High DPI Support(void)" (?CefEnableHighDPISupport@@YAXXZ)
> in the function *main. CEF_my_example
> C:\Users\Staxcel\source\repos\VS2019\Pak\CEF*\CEF_my_example.obj 1

I can't figure out where and what I forgot to specify or include?

Why does this error occur in this case ?

Comment: Are you using CefSharp? If not please remove the tag

Comment: @amaitland, deleted.

Comment: Thanks.  If you don't have any luck here then try the CEF support forum at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php

Comment: @amaitland, at first I wanted to apply there, but I can't register there in any way - I don't receive an activation letter. So I decided to ask here.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2962/unable-to-register-in-your-forums#comment-58930391

Comment: @amaitland, thank you very much!

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib,cef_sandbox.lib")` - is this a typo, or are you missing a `"`?

Comment: @zenzelezz, oh, it's a typo of course. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you want to use is defined in the libcef.lib, so you need to include that one too.
Also you will need the libcef_dll_wrapper. Both are used by the cef-examples too.

Try to add them, and see if it loads then

```
#pragma comment(lib,"libcef.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"libcef_dll_wrapper.lib")
```